# space not working while writing code in go language in visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I have some problems while writing go code in visual studio code. when try to write some comments space doesn't work after each word, the space gets deleted automatically. Need some suggestions about what may be causing this error, It also happened when I was defining some attributes in my function.
Also note that I have my autosaver on and go extension installed!!

for example in the below code:

[image: If I try to add "," after 404 not found string, the "," automatically gets deleted]

If I try to add "," after 404 not found string, the "," automatically gets deleted.

Comment: what is your autosaver?

Comment: Did you trigger file save explicitly? (AFAIK auto-save shouldn't trigger formatting) 
Can you share the full settings.json?

Comment: autosaver is "Save typing"

Comment: No I did not trigger save explicitly.

Comment: Setting.json
`{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -javaagent:\"/Users/shamanthkm/.vscode/extensions/gabrielbb.vscode-lombok-1.0.1/server/lombok.jar\"",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "java.imports.gradle.wrapper.checksums": [
        {
            "sha256": "ebb6eaf164c425ffe76f9744a324feb774e750d821ed212d4c41f452adea248e",
            "allowed": true
        }
    ],
    "window.zoomLevel": 1
}`

Comment: Problem solved after updating GO extension in visual studio code.
Thanks